# Using Post() from httr packages to catch href in R

Tags: javascript, r, rvest, httr

at the moment i'm trying to catch hrefs of different events listed at a specific page. The content of this page is generated by JavaScript and has two pages. Crawling and handling the first page is no big deal, but i'm unable to crawl the second page.
I already tried to use the post() method from httr but the crawled data is still the content from the first page.
This is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
res <- POST("http://www.pg-sanderau.de/aktuelles---termine/#page2",
     encode="form",
     user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.50 Safari/537.36"),
     add_headers(`Referer`="http://www.pg-sanderau.de/aktuelles---termine/#page2"))
res_t <- content(res, as="text")
res_h <- paste0(unlist(strsplit(res_t, "\r\n"))[-1], sep="", collapse="\n")
res_h %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(".itemtitle a")%>%
  html_attr("href") -> Links1
Links1 <- data.frame(Links1)
```

So my dataframes contains the ten hrefs from the first page "http://www.pg-sanderau.de/aktuelles---termine/#page1" but not the last four from the second page. Am i using the wrong package or is my approach incorrect?

Very help would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The page is always loading `page1` and loading `page2` through javascript if the url has `#page2`. You can check the network tab to get the `url` from which page is getting information for page2

Comment: Oh yeahr it worked but this is an static way to do that. 
My goal is to automate this progress in R.

Comment: So i tried to download a static html file generated out of JS with the post()-method. In theory this should work but i don't know why my code isn't working.

Comment: aah, you are fetching the html file as a string and loading it in virtual DOM and reading it. However the javascript code will not be executed so your DOM will not be updated. You might need a virtual browser to do that, I dont know much about R so i dont know if there is any

Answer (score 0):

Okay PhantomJS just worked fine for me.